# What's the fastest way in C++ to concat a list of variables in different types to a comma separated string?

Tags: c++, ostringstream

```
string A = "test";
double B = 123.45;
float  C = 43.23;
char   D = 'c';
```

Trying to join them to product a string `string res = "test,123.45,43.23,c"`. What is the fastest way?

`ostringstream` is good, but seems not fast enough.

Comment: Can you quantify 'not fast enough'? How many variables to do have and how many time you will output it to a string?

Comment: @rvdk why don't we just face it. stringstream is good in some situations but joining strings is overkill. Performance wise and memory use are all not optimal

Comment: try `reserve` on the output string, it can help a lot. Also, there may be dedicated library's for this, try google StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

you can always use the `C` way:

```
char outbuf[256];
sprintf(outbuf, "%s,%3.2d,%2.2f,%c", A.c_str(), B, C, D);
```

note that the line I wrote is highly specific; because you didn't precise anything about the format for the doubles, floats, string length,...

Comment: This code is prone to buffer overflows. If e.g. A.length()>=256 there is a significant problem.

Comment: I know; he is just asking a fast way :) but your remark is correct

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the fastest way. I simply know how it can be done in C++.:)

Here is a demonstrative program that shows two approaches

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    std::string A = "test";
    double B = 123.45;
    float  C = 43.23;
    char   D = 'c'; 

    std::string res1 = A + ',' + std::to_string( B ) + ',' + 
                       std::to_string( C ) + ',' + D;

    std::cout << res1 << std::endl;

    std::ostringstream is;

    is << A << ',' << B << ',' << C << ',' << D;

    std::string res2 = is.str();

    std::cout << res2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
test,123.450000,43.230000,c
test,123.45,43.23,c
```

So you can select what you like.:)

To make the methods faster you should reserve enough memory for strings using member function `reserve`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem consists of two tasks:

- convert the variables to strings
- concatenate the strings to a single string.

The second step can be sped up by reserving some memory using std::string::reserve(). Normally std::string will have to reallocate memory several times when repeatedly appending to the end. This can be avoided if the size of the resulting string is known ahead of time. std::string::reserve() then can be used to tell std::string about it so that it can reduce the calls to reallocate the memory which may significantly improve performance for long strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ostringstream` is a very good methods, "**seems not fast enough**" may be not so important unless you have a lot of numbers and strings to cat.

maybe `[sprintf][1]` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

is a alterative, I think this may be faster if you know the length of the result:

you make a `new char[length]` at the beginning.

For example:

```
char * buffer = new char[LENGTH];
int a = 1;
double b = 2.0;
string c = "3.0";
int n = sprintf(buffer, "%d plus %f is %s", a, b, c.c_str());
```

In Addition, `snprintf` is suggested because it is more safe

Answer (score 0):

Under Visual Studio 2013, sprintf is two times faster than ostringstream (measured in release). The reason is probably because ostringstream does a lot of allocations, I have used _CrtSetAllocHook and it is triggered 74 times for below code sample, while it is not even once triggered for sprintf - this was measured in debug.

ps. stringstream can be customized, you can write your own custom buffer which will be optimal for your needs.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct TimeMe {
    ULONG64 start;
    TimeMe() {
        QueryThreadCycleTime(GetCurrentThread(), &start);
    }
    ULONG64 total() {
        ULONG64 end;
        QueryThreadCycleTime(GetCurrentThread(), &end);
        return (end - start);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string A = "test";
    double B = 123.45;
    float  C = 43.23;
    char   D = 'c';

    char outbuf[256];
    std::ostringstream is;

    ULONG64 sum=0;
    for ( int k = 0; k < 100; ++k ) {
        TimeMe me;

        // ~8800 ticks
        //is.str("");
        //is.clear();
        //is << A << ',' << B << ',' << C << ',' << D;
        //std::string res2 = is.str();

        // ~4500 ticks
        sprintf(outbuf, "%s,%3.2lf,%2.2f,%c", A.c_str(), B, C, D);

        sum += me.total();
    }
    std::cout << "CPU ticks: " << (sum)/100 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```